# After instaLLING IT WANTS to install again

Tags: boot

After installing ubuntu and restarting (yes i ejected the harddrive aND restarted after that) it shows me the install screen again so after i click out of it (i have it installed already) its working but its really slow and donwloading is not working

Comment: Are you saying that 1) After you have disconnected all install media, and 2) After rebooting, then your hardware boots into an installer?

Answer (score 3):

This is a common occurrence, and it can occur for two broad reasons.

1. The new user failed to remove the install media (like a LiveUSB) before rebooting into the installed system. So the system rebooted into the installer again. The solution is to simply try rebooting again. This time, remove the install media first.
2. The new user failed to follow [the instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/) carefully. Usually, his means they took a shortcut or skipped a step or tried to install without using a USB stick at all, etc. Shortcuts and skipping steps don't work. The solution is to start over: Make the LiveUSB properly, and use it to install Ubuntu.

Lots of folks say "*but something *different* happened to me!*" Years of experience helping them troubleshoot have shown that's almost never true. It always turns out to be one of the same two reasons.

- Fun fact to help diagnose: A properly installed Ubuntu system does not include an installer (why would it?) So if you are encountering an installer, you're NOT booting into a properly-installed Ubuntu system.

Comment: i meant the ubuntu iso and it doesnt tell me where i wanna install it

Comment: It did, in this particular step. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation You can choose the partition to install Ubuntu

Comment: I dont see the opinion to choose disk which is up on the picture with full erase

Comment: It like spams me with bunch of things when i take the drive out and restart and it not works

Comment: @Los_pepos your original question says "*After installing Ubuntu...it shows me the install screen again*" so that's what this answers.

Comment: Comments here should address ways to improve this answer. Please don't try to modify or explain your question in comments. Edit your question instead to be more clear, more complete, and offer more information. Better questions get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

After installation, during reboot, remove the USB drive/DVD you used to install Ubuntu.

Then, the computer will boot from the installed version (assuming the installation went well).

Comment: so i had the booting thing on externel hard drive but it auto installed on my comp hd?

Comment: You had been asked "Where to install Ubuntu?" during installation. You can choose a partition in the internal hard drive. Also, disconnect the external hard drive after installation.

Comment: i have not been asked where